# Maximal eigenvalue of a matrix as a function of three variables

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

Assume that $A$ is a positive square real matrix of size  $4\times 4$ along with three variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$ (all are positive real numbers):

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
  1     & x_1   & 2   &x_3\\
  1/x_1 & 1     & x_2 & 1/5 \\
  1/2   & 1/x_2 & 1   & 3\\
  1/x_3 & 5     & 1/3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

My question is, how to find the **maximal eigenvalue** of $A$?

---

When I write the following on a MATLAB commands, I will get functions. So, which function will be considered as the **maximal eigenvalue** (as a function of three variables)?

```
>> syms x1 x2 x3;

>> A=[1    x1   2   x3;
      1/x1 1    x2  1/5;
      1/2  1/x2 1   3;
      1/x3 5    1/3 1]; 
>> e=eig(A)
```

Please help? Thanks

---

**Perron–Frobenius Theorem:** A real square matrix with positive entries has a unique largest real eigenvalue and that the corresponding eigenvector can be chosen to have strictly positive components.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Depending on what you want you may be better off just looking at finitely many points instead of the symbolic form.

Comment: What is  Matlab's answer?

Comment: @Gribouillis It's long. With four lengthy functions. It'll fill the screen if I post it here.

Comment: @Griboullis Matlab's answers are four untractable 1 km long formulas.

Comment: Following up on what Jean Marie said, that really shouldn't be any surprised because all that's happening is it is using the quartic formula on the characteristic polynomial. It might not be doing that internally, but it is equivalent in a situation as general as this.

Answer (score 1):

**A partial answer.**

The characteristic polynomial of $A$

$\chi(x):=x^4+c_1x^3+c_2x^2+c_3x+c_4 \tag{1}$

has $c_1=-tr(A)=-4$ (notation "tr" for trace) and

$$c_2=\dfrac{1}{2!}\begin{vmatrix}tr(A)&1\\tr(A^2)&tr(A)\end{vmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{vmatrix}4&1\\16&4\end{vmatrix}=0 \tag{2}$$

(indeed $tr(A)=4$ and $tr(A^2)=16$ by an easy computation).

(I use in (2) a formula that can be found for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial)).

As a consequence of (1) and (2), an eigenvalue $x$ of $A$ is such that :

$$\chi(x)=x^4-4x^3+c_3x+c_4=0 \tag{3}$$

Remarks :

1) Formulas for $c_3$ and $c_4$ (as obtained with Matlab symbolic toolbox) are very intricated.

2) Please note that there is no term in $x^2$.

We know (as said by the author of the question) that by Perron-Frobenius theorem, $A$ has at least a real root; therefore, we have at least 2 real roots (indeed, a polynomial equation with real coefficients has complex roots coming by pairs, like in Noah's Arch).

> Extensive simulations show that there are always 2 real roots and 2 complex (conjugate) roots of (3). Moreover, Matlab is able to give symbolic formulas for the roots $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ in this order. We can observe that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the two real roots (always with $x_2$ the largest one) and the third and fourth are always (conjugate) complex ; I have no proof for these facts.

Among the real roots, $x_2$ is very dominant, compared with $x_1.$

**Additional remarks :** the formula for the determinant of $A$ is factorizable into simple factors :

$$ c_4=\det(A)=(15x_2 - 1)(x_1x_2 - 2)(x_1 - 5x_3)(x_3 - 6)/(30x_1x_2x_3).$$

2) The fact that there are necessarily at least two real roots can be established without Perron-Frobenius. It is due to the absence of the $x^2$ term ; indeed setting to zero the coefficient of the missing term in $x^2$ :

$$x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4=0\tag{4}$$

If on the contrary, we had two pairs of ( conjugated) complex roots, say with $x_2=\bar{x_1}$ and $x_4=\bar{x_3}$, we could transform (4) into :

$$|x_1|^2+2 \Re(x_1) \Re(x_3)+|x_3|^2=0$$

which is possible only if $x_1=x_3=0$, but in this case, we have a double real root !

3) The fact that (apparently) the second formula always gives the largest eigenvalus can be considered as exceptional. For example, the family of matrices :

$$A_x=\begin{pmatrix}0&x\\x&0\end{pmatrix}$$

has the following formulas for its eigenvalues :

$$x_1=x, \ \ x_2=-x$$

on which we can see that the largest eigenvalue is given by the second formula when $x<0$ and by the first one when $x>0$...

Comment: @JeanMsince we have got four functions, one of them must be the greatest real eigenvalue (as a functuon of three variables ). So, which function contributes for the maximal eigenvale on MATLAB command window by default?  The 1st, 2nd, 3rd or the 4th one? This is my question. Thanks

Comment: I have modified my answer. Something I have observed (but not proven) is that it is always the root with the second formula given by Matlab which gives the largest real eigenvalue.

Comment: Please, have a look to the last remark I just added.